# Writing a chain of `catchError`-s with `(<|>)`?

Tags: haskell, error-handling, monad-transformers

In the following code, is there a more idiomatic way to write the `checks` function?

The pattern feels a lot like `(<|>)` should work here, but using

```
checks s = check1 s <|> check2 s <|> throwError "..."
```

requires me to define `instance Error ByteString`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Bar where

import Data.ByteString.Char8 (ByteString)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BS

import Control.Monad
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.Error
import Data.Monoid

check1 str =
  if str == "abc"
    then return 1
    else throwError ("not equal to abc" :: ByteString)

check2 str =
  if str == "def"
    then return 2
    else throwError ("not equal to def" :: ByteString)

checks str = (check1 str)
               `catchError` (const (check2 str))
               `catchError` (const (throwError "not abc or def"))

main :: IO ()
main = do
  input <- BS.getLine
  case checks input of
    Left e  -> BS.putStrLn $ "Error: " <> e
    Right a -> BS.putStrLn "OK"
```

Answer (score 4):

The `Alternative` instance for `Either` uses an `Error` constraint to generate a value for `empty :: Alternative f => f a`. In this case, it does something like `empty = Left noMsg :: Error e => Either e a`. Since using `<|>` doesn't actually need the error instance, if you want `<|>` without `empty`, you could use [`Data.Functor.Alt.Alt`](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.8/20140916-162/semigroupoids/Data-Functor-Alt.html) from semigroupoids.

However, `ExceptT` from `Control.Monad.Except` or `Control.Monad.Trans.Except` uses a more sensible `Monoid` constraint, and `Bytestring` is a `Monoid` already. I believe that `ErrorT` is deprecated now because of this. You also may want to use a list of `Bytestring`s as your error type, or else the `Bytestring`s will be concatenated together with no spacing.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Bar where

import Data.ByteString.Char8 (ByteString)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BS

import Control.Monad
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.Trans.Except 
import Data.Monoid

check1 str =
  if str == "abc"
    then return 1
    else throwE ["not equal to abc" ]

check2 str =
  if str == "def"
    then return 2
    else throwE ["not equal to def" ]

checks str = check1 str <|> check2 str <|> throwE ["not abc or def"]

main :: IO ()
main = do
  input <- BS.getLine
  case runExcept $ checks input of
    Left e  -> mapM_ (BS.putStrLn . ("Error: " <>)) e 
    Right a -> print a
```

Comment: What's interesting is that the default definition for `instance Error ByteString` is enough to resolve the problem in my original code using `<|>`. But the default method definitions for `noMsg` and `strMsg` are defined in terms of each other. So apparently `noMsg` doesn't actually get called. Is that correct?

Comment: If you just declare `instance Error Bytestring` then calling `noMsg` or `strMsg` will produce an infinite loop.

Comment: Yeah - that's the weird thing. In order to use `<|>` I have to define `instance Error ByteString`, but the `Error` methods `noMsg` and `strMsg` never get called.

Comment: @user5402 Correct; as stated in the answer, `empty` uses `noMsg`, but `<|>` doesn't. (And `fail` uses `strMsg`, in case you're wondering why that's in the class.)

Comment: Ok - I found this in the GHC Trac which helped explain things: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9588